# Is it possible to copy data from a local SQL Server database on a regular basis to an online SQL Server database and vice versa?

Tags: sql-server, database, web-hosting

I have to host a website online that will need to access data on a local database. Therefore, I want to use an hosted database containing the data needed from the local one. The website will also write data in the hosted database that need to be copied to the local database. Is this process achievable ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Server Replication

Comment: Yes, since 2000, through a *lot* of different features, including replication, synchronization, or simply posting data from the local database to the remote through a scheduled job or script. Different features have different advantages and disadvantages. Do you even have access to the hosted database though? Or do you need to set up a VPN? For security reasons hosters *don't* expose databases on the public internet

Comment: How much data do you need to copy and how often?

Comment: I have not yet chosen which web hoster to use. 
About the quantity of data to copy, there aren't much data at the moment (few thousands of rows). I'd like to copy the data 1 time a day. What could be the best solution ?

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why do you need to copy/replicate the data? It complicates your overall solution significantly and is best avoided if possible.

Comment: The website will use data from my company's database that I can't host. Moreover I only need few of its tables. Replicating the data would be keep the website up to date.